# Generator for multipart form data with python requests

Tags: python

I've been monkeying around with this [Zipstream](https://github.com/SpiderOak/ZipStream) module by SpiderOak that basically allows you to stream and zip  file or folder without writing anything to disc. It yields chunks of irregularly sized data.

Now, I am trying to upload a directory to a file hosting site that requires me to send `file` and `apikey` fields inside a post request.  With requests I have to build a dict for the apikey like so:

```
data = {'apikey': 'myapikey'}
```

and also read the entire zipstream into a string and pass it to a file-encoding dict:

```
files = {'file': ('mydir.zip', the_string_that_is_a_zipped_dir)}
```

then issue the request

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files).
```

This works ok. However I would like to transfer larger stuff in the future and reading the entire file in memory is a BAD idea to begin with. 
I saw in the requests advanced section that you could send a generator as the data field, but then I can't send the api key and have to modify headers manually to set the content type and all that stuff so it doesn't work. Also tried to form a dictionary out of the api key and zip file generator like so 
data = {
  'file': ('mydir.zip', generator()),
  'apikey': 'myapikey'
}

but this fails (as expected).

Is there a way to hack requests into using a generator that yields strings for a file in a multipart form-data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some struggle I managed to make this working without requests, instead using the module [poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/).

First I created a fileobject wrapper around zipstream like so:

```
from zipstream import ZipStream

class Zipit:
  def __init__( self, path):
    self.it = iter(ZipStream(path,compression=0))
    self.next_chunk = ""
    self.length = -1
    self.path = path
    self.__is_zipit__=''    
  @property
  def size(self):
    if self.length < 0:
      self.length = 0
      zip_object = ZipStream(self.path,compression=0)
      for data in zip_object:
        self.length += len(data)
    return self.length

  def growChunk( self ):
    self.next_chunk = self.next_chunk + self.it.next()
  def read( self, n ):
    if self.next_chunk == None:
      return None
    try:
      while len(self.next_chunk)<n:
        self.growChunk()
      rv = self.next_chunk[:n]
      self.next_chunk = self.next_chunk[n:]
      return rv
    except StopIteration:
      rv = self.next_chunk
      self.next_chunk = None
      return rv
```

in order to have an easy api (code shamelessly adapted from another example on SO).

Then as per poster's doc create the necessary multipart objects:

```
z = Zipit('/my/path/to/zip')

f = MultipartParam('file', fileobj=z, filesize=z.size, filename='test.zip',filetype='application/zip')
datagen, headers = multipart_encode([ f, ('akey', 'mykey')])
```

One last hack is skipping the reset in case the fileobject field is a Zipit instance:

```
   def reset(self):
        if hasattr(self.fileobj, '__is_zipit__'): return
        if self.fileobj is not None:
            self.fileobj.seek(0)
        elif self.value is None:
            raise ValueError("Don't know how to reset this parameter")
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps any of the five of you that read this.